# Using Instruments to test an iOS app without having source code to the application

Tags: ios, ipad, automated-tests, instruments, ui-automation

I would like to use UIAutomation via Instruments in Xcode to test an app on my iOS device. Is it possible to do so without having to build the source code? The reason for this is that our team will have testers who will be writing automation scripts to test the apps on our devices, but we don't want them to all go through syncing to latest builds and compiling it through Xcode. Does anyone know if this is possible through UIAutomation or possibly through a 3rd party application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make UIAutomation tests without the source code, but you will not see your symbols and you cant see where in your code your app is hanging.

You still can see if there is a routine that is taking to long to run, but you wont e able to see witch one or the call stack

to make your tests without the source code just open the automator and bind your test with an application installed on the device

Comment: Could you be more specific? how to bind test with installed app?