# Using Instruments to test an iOS app without having source code of the application

Tags: ios, ipad, ui-automation, xcode-instruments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Instruments to test an iOS app without having source code to the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045621/using-instruments-to-test-an-ios-app-without-having-source-code-to-the-applicati)

I should like to make UI automation tests for native and web iOS applications (on iPad device or iPad simulator) via XCode Instruments tool. There is no application source code. 
How can I use Instruments Automation tamplate with real device and with simulator in this case?

Details:
I am able to select target for Instruments choosing Product>Profile, while some XCode project is opened, but it is useful in the case if there is source code. Maybe I must create some specific project that will just run simulator and stay on the home page?
But from the Instruments I cann't choose neither real device (it is listed, but disabled - coloured with light grey) nor simulator (it prompts to select some app from Mac book). Is it at all possible to make UI automation tests on iOS simulator via Instruments without source code?

I need to make iOS simulator/real device ready to write UI automation tests for it.

Comment: The question is not 'whether' it is possible to use UIAutomation through Instruments for testing without source code at all. But how can I make it not only on real device, but on Simulator? Is it possible?