# iOS App Testing without Xcode project file

Tags: ios, automated-tests, xcode5, xcode-instruments

I have requirement to test an iOS App on iPhone using instruments which comes along with Xcode5. But the problem is i dont have xcode project file instead i have an app downloaded from customer site nor they are willing to share project file. So please let me know if it is possible to identify native objects of app using Instruments?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045621/using-instruments-to-test-an-ios-app-without-having-source-code-to-the-applicati).

Comment: You are right!! thanq Very much

Answer (score 0):

No, you can just test the app for leaks. You can identify its native objects only in case they are provided open without zip. I think so.